# The Hidden Wiki not opening

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, windows

After installing the last version of Tor, connection works good (I checked it ). When I open the [hidden wiki](http://kpvz7ki2v5agwt35.onion/), it doesn't work. After long time loading it tells me `The connection has timed out`.
Is there another link?

Comment: Can you try it again? http://kpvz7ki2v5agwt35.onion/wiki/index.php/Main_Page works from here. Can you access the log file? If yes, are there messages around the time you're accessing the hidden wiki?

Comment: it doesn't work, how to access the log file?

Comment: You need to enable the log file. Go to the directory where you installed/unpacked TBB. In Data/Tor is `torrc`. Add the line `Log info file log.txt` and start Tor. The file log.txt maybe contains useful information.

Comment: The log file tell me this http://en.textsave.org/lhO
Please help me

Answer (score 2):

The Hidden Wiki is now down. Doxbin took over the kvpz onion domain and redirects it to Doxbin. So now use this link :

https://kpvz7ki2lzvnwve7.onion.to/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 2):

I found another link to Hidden Wiki. I think now it's this one:

http://kpvz7kpmcmne52qf.onion/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

The hidden wiki is not down, tor upgraded to V3 safer address type thus the address you list above now redirects to the v3 updated hidden wiki link :

http://zqktlwiuavvvqqt4ybvgvi7tyo4hjl5xgfuvpdf6otjiycgwqbym2qad.onion/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

If a hidden service isn't working for you then it's probably down. To confirm that nothing is wrong with Tor itself visit the main Tor Project website as Hidden service:
http://idnxcnkne4qt76tg.onion/